# Doctrine 2 How do I add a record to a join table that has no entity?

Tags: doctrine-orm

Having a hard time wrapping my head around this one. I have a Page entity and a Keyword entity. I've created a member variable called $keywords in my Page entity that has a ManyToMany association that creates a join table called "pages_keywords". In my application, I want to give the ability to add a keyword to a page. How would I go about adding that record to the database?

I can access the Page entity's $keywords member variable but I'm not sure where to go from there. I see that the Doctrine implementation of ArrayCollection has an add() method that just takes a value. Can I just pass it the Keyword entity's id and will that create the record for me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you know the primary key value of the entity you are looking to associate it with (in your example, the $keywordId), the best way to do this is to get a reference to the entity.  This gets you a reference without doing a database lookup for the associated entity.

The solution you posted in your follow-up answer has the disadvantage of requiring an extra trip to the database to retrieve the keyword record.  Retrieving it as a reference means that there is no extra database lookup:

```
<?php

// assumes $this->em is already defined as the Doctrine2 EntityManager
$page = $this->em->getRepository('App\Entity\Page')->find($pageId);

// associate $keyword with $page via a reference to the keywordId
$keyword = $this->em->getReference('App\Entity\Keyword', $keywordId);
$page->getKeywords()->add($keyword);
$em->flush();
```

Comment: I really like this approach and need to start using it.

Answer (score 1):

I seem to answer a lot of my own questions for some reason. :)

Figured this one out. I just grab my Page object and the Keyword object I want to add to tha page, then get the keywords and use the add() method passing in the keyword object.

```
// Assuming you have an instance of the Entity Manager
$page = $this->em->getRepository('App\Entity\Page')->find($pageId);
$keyword= $this->em->getRepository('App\Entity\Keyword')->find($keywordId);
$page->getKeywords()->add($keyword);
$em->persist($page);
$em->flush();
```

Comment: This is not good, You are retrieving the entity from the database, when in fact only one reference to it is needed. $em->getReference is the best way to do this.

Comment: Yeah, I've since learned that. Look at the accepted answer and my comment there.